# API Gateway - Transformation and Asynchronous Messaging

Tags: esb, microservices, aws-api-gateway

Does API Gateway handle the aspects of Transformation of Request/Responses for/from multiple APIs Or does it ideally handle this aspect at all?

How does it fit in the landscape where Asynchronous messaging is used instead of Synchronous REST call?

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by from multiple APIs? Do you mean that if you can create a method with multiple backend APIs, API Gateway will collect all the responses from them then perform a transformation?

Comment: @KaHouIeong - It can happen in different ways; 
Scenario 1 - The calls to multiple APIs are orchestrated by API Gateway (may not be ideal scenario) and the final response is transformed into client specific format.
Scenario 2 - A single call from the APIGateway to Composite Service API that orchestrates calls to diff APIs and responds back to APIGateway where the final response is transformed into client specific format.